# Swift 3 : Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled

Tags: json, swift, swift3

I am in the process of converting my old swift 2.2 code to swift 3. The following class is used to send HTTP Requests to a webserver and then get back result data in json format.

```
typealias ServiceResponse = (JSON, NSError?) -> Void

class RESTManager:NSObject{

    static let sharedInstance = RESTManager()

    let baseRestUrl = SysSettingsService.getBaseRestUrl()

    class func makeHTTPGETRequest(_ path:String, onCompletion:@escaping ServiceResponse){
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: URL(string:path)!)
        let session = URLSession.shared
        let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
            let json:JSON = JSON(data: data!) // where I get the error
            onCompletion(json, error! as NSError)
        })
        task.resume()
    }

}
```

However, I get an error in the line `let json:JSON = JSON(data: data!)` saying:

> Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not
>   handled

I looked at the many questions that have been asked for this error in swift 2, and all of them point to using do catch statements in case the data was not returned in json.

I tried this:

```
   do {let json:JSON = JSON(data: data!)
            onCompletion(json, error! as NSError)

            }
            catch let jsonError as NSError {
                print(jsonError.localizedDescription)
            }
```

but it did not work. The error changes to:

> Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try'

Can someone explain the issue here?

Comment: Update your question with your attempt to use do/catch and explain the issue you had.

Comment: @rmaddy added explaination

Comment: Where's your use of `try`?

Comment: @rmaddy that does it! 
`let json:JSON = try JSON(data: data!)` . i will add an answer and thanks!

Comment: The duplicate answer is about Swift 2 and a different API but the issue is the same.